# procedure to upgrade Puppet Master in RHOS

Tags: puppet

Using puppet version 3.6.2.

How can I upgrade puppet master version in RHOS.

Do I need to make any change in agent node?

Comment: RHOS version is 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)

Comment: tried to connect to puppet master installed in RHOS 6.6 from puppet agent installed in RHOS 7..

Comment: $puppet agent --test
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve local facts: undefined method `to_a' for "ens160":String
Error: Failed to apply catalog: Could not retrieve local facts: undefined method `to_a' for "ens160":String

Comment: Can you use a supported version?

Comment: i did not get you...do i need to upgrade puppet master OS to 7..if so do i need to upgrade puppet master  because puppet agent is 3.8.2